# HDF5 `h5repack` Error ocurred while repacking

Tags: hdf5, h5py

I'm running the following `h5repack` command on a new HDF5 file. I've repacked files in the past without any problem, but this HDF5 file is not cooperating. Possibly it's due to the grouping structure, I access the table I'm interested in via `h5py.File(filepath)['recordings/rec0000/well000/groups/routed/raw']`. In this related question I confirmed the way to reference the group structure on the command line. However, I'm still getting the error seen below.

```
$ h5repack -v -f /recordings/rec0000/well000/groups/routed/raw:NONE -i 230208_c10984.h5 -o 230208_c10984.uncompressed.h5
No all objects to modify layout
No all objects to apply filter
 </recordings/rec0000/well000/groups/routed/raw> with NONE filter
Opening file. Searching 52 objects to modify ...
 </recordings/rec0000/well000/groups/routed/raw>Error occurred while repacking
```

Here's the (relevant?) part of `h5dump -pH 230208_c10984.h5`

```
               DATASET "raw" {
                  DATATYPE  H5T_STD_U16LE
                  DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 880, 6000000 ) / ( 880, H5S_UNLIMITED ) }
                  STORAGE_LAYOUT {
                     CHUNKED ( 880, 200 )
                     SIZE 1449463146 (7.285:1 COMPRESSION)
                  }
                  FILTERS {
                     USER_DEFINED_FILTER {
                        FILTER_ID 401
                        COMMENT mxw-data
                     }
                     COMPRESSION DEFLATE { LEVEL 0 }
                  }
                  FILLVALUE {
                     FILL_TIME H5D_FILL_TIME_IFSET
                     VALUE  H5D_FILL_VALUE_DEFAULT
                  }
                  ALLOCATION_TIME {
                     H5D_ALLOC_TIME_INCR
                  }
               }
```

I also tried to change the `--layout=/recordings/rec0000/well0000/groups/routed/raw:CHUNKED=1x30000` with a similar error.

I verify here that I can open and access the dataset in `h5py`:

```
import h5py

>>> h5py.File('230208_c10984.h5')['recordings/rec0000/well000/groups/routed/raw']
<HDF5 dataset "raw": shape (880, 6000000), type "<u2">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my 2nd answer. It addresses the custom filter in the `h5repack` output.

The h5repack output for `FILTERS {}` shows `FILTER_ID 401`. This is a custom compression filter.  I checked the [Registered Filter Plugins at The HDF Group](https://portal.hdfgroup.org/display/support/Registered+Filter+Plugins), and there isn't a `401` listed. I'm pretty sure h5repack doesn't know about this filter. You can check my assumption by trying to print the data in the dataset. Modify your `h5dump` command to: :

```
h5dump -d /recordings/rec0000/well000/groups/routed/raw -s=1 -c=10 230208_c10984.h5
Note: -d defines dataset name, -s and -c limit the output to a small slice
```

If you get an error printing the data, I'm 99% sure the problem is a missing filter. You can check to see which HDF5 plugins are installed in this folder: `$HDF5_HOME/lib/plugin`.

You can also check filter behavior with h5py by getting the `.compression` attribute for the dataset. The 1st line prints compression filter name and the 2nd line prints the 1st 10 data values. That will test to see if h5py has the compression filter installed.

```
with h5py.File(filepath) as h5f:
    ds = h5f['recordings/rec0000/well000/groups/routed/raw']
    print(ds.name, ds.compression)
    print(ds[0:10,0])
```

I don't know if this will solve your problem, but should get you pointed in the right direction. If the problem is the filter, you need to figure out what filter ID 401 is, then how to get the libraries and install them in the plugin folder so h5repack can access them. Good luck!

Comment: It was indeed the user defined filter. Once I corrected a path issue so the plugin was properly accessible, I was able to run the `h5repack` successfully. Thanks for the great answer here!

Comment: Glad that helped. I was afraid you would be stuck trying to resolve an undocumented filter (especially a filter you didn't have). Apparently ID=401 means something to you. :-)

Comment: Yeah, the filter has been thorny enough that just saying the word "custom filter" was enough to trigger the appropriate fear response. But you pointing out that `ID=401` was a custom plugin, not known to H5 group, helped pull together a number of disparate threads for me. A bigger problem still was that my path `/recordings/rec0000/well000/groups/routed/raw` was actually a link to the group structure `/data_store/data0000/groups/routed/raw`, and `h5repack` doesn't accept links. Since I didn't know what H5 links were until yesterday, that was another prickly confound.

Answer (score 1):

This was my 1st answer. It addresses an error in the dataset name used in the `h5repack` command:

Count your zeros - I think you have an extra one.
Comparing the Python code to the h5repack command:

```
h5py.File(filepath)['recordings/rec0000/well000/groups/routed/raw']
rec0000 has 4 zeros and well000 has 3 zeros

$ h5repack -v -f /recordings/rec0000/well0000/groups/routed/raw:NONE
rec0000 has 4 zeros and well0000 has 4 zeros
```

Comment: Wow, you're absolutely correct, I had the wrong number of zero's, however when I fix that I end up with the same error. I've updated the question now with the verification I ran and with the error copy/pasted with the command and correct group path.